# Invoke an static delegate from Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, static

I have the folowing lines:

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static Func<object,string> Bar = myObject => myObject.ToString();
}
```

There is no way to perform something like `Foo.Bar(someObject);` using reflection in C#. As I can see Bar is not a Method, is a Field, of course, and I can't use `MethodInfo.Invoke();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the value of the property through reflection. It's a delegate, so call it's Invoke method either directly (cast to the appropriate type if you will know that statically) or through reflection.